# I get null returned value from a method. Flutter

Tags: flutter, return, return-value

I'm very new to Flutter/Dart and I'm using the flutter_bloc bloc/repository pattern.

I'm struggling to getting a value from a repository method and I get null in the bloc method.

The bloc part is working fine but the expected LatLng value I get form repository method is null.

bloc's value and Event to State method :

```
LatLng locationStream;    

Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationStreamToState(
          GetLocationStream event) async* {
        print('_mapGetLocationStreamToState event received : $event');

        locationStream = await _mapRepository.getLocationStream();
        print('_mapGetLocationStreamToState() locationStream is: $locationStream ');
        yield LocationStream(locationStream);
      }
```

prints:

> flutter: _mapGetLocationStreamToState() locationStream is: null
>
> flutter: Transaction is Transition { currentState: LocationStream
>   {location: null}, event: Instance of 'GetLocationStream', nextState:
>   LocationStream {location: null} }

I tried both `T` and `Future<T>` return types for repository method, returning the value from different scopes (see commented out returns) but I always get null no matter where I return the value from.
Can you spot where the problem is?
It should be in `getLocation()` method right?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

T:

```
    LatLng getLocationStream() {
    print('getLocationStream() called');
    LatLng location;
    LocationOptions locationOptions = LocationOptions(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 0);
    try {
      if (isTracking == true) {
        _positionStreamSubsciption.cancel();
        isTracking = !isTracking;
      } else {
        _positionStreamSubsciption = locationManager
            .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
            .listen((Position position) {
          if (position != null) {
            location = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
//            return location; // stops the stream
          }
          isTracking = !isTracking;
          print('getLocationStream() location is : $location');
//          return location; // returns null
        });
//        return location; // returns null
      }
//      return location; // returns null
    } catch (error) {
      print('startTracking error: $error');
    }
    return location; // returns null
  }
```

prints:

> flutter: getLocationStream() location is : LatLng(latitude:37.33022,
>   longitude:-122.023788) flutter: getLocationStream() location is :
>   LatLng(latitude:37.330219, longitude:-122.023748) flutter:
>   getLocationStream() location is : LatLng(latitude:37.330219,
>   longitude:-122.023708) flutter: getLocationStream() location is :
>   LatLng(latitude:37.330221, longitude:-122.023668)

Future :

```
Future<LatLng> getLocationStream() {
    print('getLocationStream() called');
    print('isTracking was : $isTracking');
    Future<LatLng> location;
    LocationOptions locationOptions = LocationOptions(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 0);
    try {
      if (isTracking == true) {
        _positionStreamSubsciption.cancel();
//        isTracking = !isTracking;
//        print('isTracking was ${!isTracking} and now is : $isTracking');
      } else {
        _positionStreamSubsciption = locationManager
            .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
            .listen((Position position) {
          if (position != null) {
            location =
                LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude) as Future<LatLng>;
//            return location;

          }
          print('getLocationStream() location is : $location');
//          return location;
        });
//        return location;
      }

      isTracking = !isTracking;
      print('isTracking is : $isTracking');
//      return location;
    } catch (error) {
      print('startTracking error: $error');
    }
  }
```

prints :

> flutter: getLocationStream() location is : LatLng(latitude:37.324746,
>   longitude:-122.021542) flutter: getLocationStream() location is :
>   LatLng(latitude:37.324746, longitude:-122.021573) flutter:
>   getLocationStream() location is : LatLng(latitude:37.324746,
>   longitude:-122.021605)

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling a bit with the code I decided to change approach, and seems that I chosen the wrong one before.
Instead of returning a LatLng from the repository method, I decided to transform the `Stream<Position> coming from`Geolocator`API directly into a`Stream, and listening to it from bloc.

Now states are flowing as expected carrying the new location value with them.

The only problem left to solve(that I actually thought I didn't have) is that `MapScren` `BlocBuilder` doesn't get hold of the value coming from the new state and I get null when using it as in `_mapController.move(userLocation, 16);`.

Isn't `LatLng userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;`the right way to get hold of it?

Updated code is:

BlocBuilder:

```
bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
        builder: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
          LatLng userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
          return Scaffold(
..
```

repository:

```
Stream<LatLng> getLocationStream() {
    print('getLocationStream() called');
    print('isTracking was : $isTracking');
    Stream<LatLng> locationStream;
    Stream<Position> _positionStream;
    LocationOptions locationOptions = LocationOptions(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 0);
    try {
      if (isTracking == true) {
        _positionStreamSubsciption.cancel();
      } else {
        _positionStream = locationManager.getPositionStream(locationOptions);

        handleData(Position position, EventSink<LatLng> sink) =>
            sink.add(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude));

        final transformer = StreamTransformer<Position, LatLng>.fromHandlers(
            handleData: handleData);
        locationStream = _positionStream.transform(transformer);
        return locationStream;
      }

      isTracking = !isTracking;
      print('isTracking is : $isTracking');
    } catch (error) {
      print('startTracking error: $error');
    }
  }
```

bloc:

```
    MapState get initialState => LocationStream(locationStream);

  @override
  Stream<MapState> mapEventToState(MapEvent event) async* {
    // user location
    if (event is GetLocationStream) {
      print('MapBloc event received : $event');
      yield* _mapGetLocationStreamToState(event);
    }
    if (event is LocationUpdated) {
      yield* _mapLocationUpdatedToState(event);
    }
  }


  Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationStreamToState(
      GetLocationStream event) async* {
    print('_mapGetLocationStreamToState event received : $event');

    _locationStreamSubscription =
        _mapRepository.getLocationStream().listen((LatLng location) {
          locationStream = location;
          add(LocationUpdated(locationStream));
          print(
              '_mapGetLocationStreamToState() locationStream is: $locationStream ');
        });

//    yield LocationStream(locationStream);
  }
```

console prints:

> flutter: Event is LocationUpdated { updtaded location:
>   LatLng(latitude:37.3246, longitude:-122.02457)} flutter:
>   _mapGetLocationStreamToState() locationStream is: LatLng(latitude:37.3246, longitude:-122.02457) flutter: Transaction is
>   Transition { currentState: LocationStream {location:
>   LatLng(latitude:37.324603, longitude:-122.024523)}, event:
>   LocationUpdated { updtaded location: LatLng(latitude:37.3246,
>   longitude:-122.02457)}, nextState: LocationStream {location:
>   LatLng(latitude:37.3246, longitude:-122.02457)} }