# BlocBuilder doesn't get hold of the value in the new State. SEE UPDATE Flutter

Tags: flutter, stream

I'm still very new to Flutter/Dart and I'm using the flutter_bloc bloc/repository pattern.
I'm struggling getting a value from a repository method back in the bloc method.
My first approach ([I get null returned value from a method. Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492758/i-get-null-returned-value-from-a-method-flutter)) was to listen to a `Stream<Position>` in a repository method and return a `LatLng` that I would get hold in my bloc method..I always got null.

So my new approach it would  be to use a `StreamTransformer` to transform that `Stream<Position>` into a `Stream<LatLng>`but I'm stuck in writing the repository method as  `.transform` seems not to be available and I get the error 
`The method 'transform' isn't defined for the class 'Function'`.
Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks as always.

My two methods are :

repository:

```
    StreamSubscription _positionStreamSubsciption;

    Stream<LatLng> getLocationStream() {
        print('getLocationStream() called');
        print('isTracking was : $isTracking');
        LatLng location;
        Stream<LatLng> locationStream;
        LocationOptions locationOptions = LocationOptions(
            accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 0);
        try {
          if (isTracking == true) {
            _positionStreamSubsciption.cancel();
          } else {
            _positionStreamSubsciption = locationManager
                .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
                .listen((Position position) {
              if (position != null) {
                location = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

                handleData(Position position, EventSink<LatLng> sink) =>
                    sink.add(location);

                final transformer =
                    StreamTransformer<Position, LatLng>.fromHandlers(
                        handleData: handleData);
                return _positionStreamSubsciption.onData.transform(transformer); // .transform trows an ERROR
              }
              print('getLocationStream() location is : $location');
            });
          }

          isTracking = !isTracking;
          print('isTracking is : $isTracking');
        } catch (error) {
          print('startTracking error: $error');
        }
      }
```

bloc :

```
    LatLng locationStream;
    StreamSubscription _locationStreamSubscription;


    Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationStreamToState(
          GetLocationStream event) async* {
        print('_mapGetLocationStreamToState event received : $event');

        _locationStreamSubscription =
            _mapRepository.getLocationStream().listen((LatLng location) {
          locationStream = location;
        });
```

UPDATE:

After fiddling a bit with the code I found out where the errors were:

1. In repository I did set a listener but instead the stream itself is needed so I added `_positionStream = locationManager.getPositionStream(locationOptions);`.
2. In `StreamTransformer`'s `handleData` I was adding to `Stream<LatLng> locationStream` a location from the listener instead that taking it from its argument `Position position`. So I changed it to `handleData(Position position, EventSink<LatLng> sink) =>
           sink.add(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude));`.
3. In bloc I also had to listen to the location stream from `_mapRepository.getLocationStream()`. Now, because yielding a state directly from inside the listener scope is not possible, and yielding it from outside the scopes just yields current stream value and doesn't update after that, I had to use an event cycle. I added to the bloc a `LocationUpdated`event passing in the location from the stream.
4. in bloc`s`mapEventToState`I had to react to that event yielding the`LocationStream` state together with the location.

Now states are flowing as expected carrying the new location value with them.

The only problem left to solve(that I actually thought I didn't have) is that `MapScren` `BlocBuilder` doesn't get hold of the value coming from the new state and I get null when using it as in `_mapController.move(userLocation, 16);`.

Isn't `LatLng userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;`the right way to get hold of it?

Updated code is:

BlocBuilder:

```
bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
        builder: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
          LatLng userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
          return Scaffold(
..
```

repository:

```
Stream<LatLng> getLocationStream() {
    print('getLocationStream() called');
    print('isTracking was : $isTracking');
    Stream<LatLng> locationStream;
    Stream<Position> _positionStream;
    LocationOptions locationOptions = LocationOptions(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation, distanceFilter: 0);
    try {
      if (isTracking == true) {
        _positionStreamSubsciption.cancel();
      } else {
        _positionStream = locationManager.getPositionStream(locationOptions);

        handleData(Position position, EventSink<LatLng> sink) =>
            sink.add(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude));

        final transformer = StreamTransformer<Position, LatLng>.fromHandlers(
            handleData: handleData);
        locationStream = _positionStream.transform(transformer);
        return locationStream;
      }

      isTracking = !isTracking;
      print('isTracking is : $isTracking');
    } catch (error) {
      print('startTracking error: $error');
    }
  }
```

bloc:

```
    MapState get initialState => LocationStream(locationStream);

  @override
  Stream<MapState> mapEventToState(MapEvent event) async* {
    // user location
    if (event is GetLocationStream) {
      print('MapBloc event received : $event');
      yield* _mapGetLocationStreamToState(event);
    }
    if (event is LocationUpdated) {
      yield* _mapLocationUpdatedToState(event);
    }
  }


  Stream<MapState> _mapGetLocationStreamToState(
      GetLocationStream event) async* {
    print('_mapGetLocationStreamToState event received : $event');

    _locationStreamSubscription =
        _mapRepository.getLocationStream().listen((LatLng location) {
          locationStream = location;
          add(LocationUpdated(locationStream));
          print(
              '_mapGetLocationStreamToState() locationStream is: $locationStream ');
        });

//    yield LocationStream(locationStream);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the last problem. In `BlocBuilder`'s `bloc:` if you pass a bloc you're actually creating a new bloc every time UI rebuilds.

That is useful for a local bloc that manages local values, but in my case `MapBloc`is a global bloc created in `main()`, so if I keep creating a new one in `MapScreen` it doesn't get the value passed in with last state, resulting in null value.
Not passing any bloc fixed it.

```
class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final MapRepository _mapRepository;
  final MapController _mapController;
  LatLng userLocation;
  MapScreen(
      {Key key, @required this.name, @required MapRepository mapRepository})
      : assert(mapRepository != null),
        _mapRepository = mapRepository,
        _mapController = MapController(),
        super(key: key);

  // v1: "lift the creation of the Map Bloc to a parent widget"
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MapBloc, MapState>(
//        bloc: MapBloc(mapRepository: _mapRepository),
        builder: (BuildContext context, MapState state) {
      userLocation = (state as LocationStream).location;
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
```

Hope this will help others starting out as Flutter is relatively new and there aren't a lot of detailed explanations about APIs making it difficult to grasp when you're just starting out..
Geolocator API Reference, for instance, is fantastic. It's clear, have detailed explanation of each class and parameter, and backed by some code example..can't ask for more and it's been a breeze implementing it.
flutter_bloc not so much(see the bloc parameter in BlocBuilder for this question), but gets you a wide range of projects covering most of your needs, so you'll find your way to understand the API anyways.
Cheers.